# What is the optimal table layout for enumeration-esque values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say you have a large number of fields, in various tables, which have integer codes that must then be cross-referenced against another table which then gives the textual representation of these codes - i.e. essentially an enumeration. Each of these codes - which appear in a number of disparate tables - would then have a foreign key against wherever the enumeration values are stored.

There are two main options:

- Store all of the enumerations in one big table which defines all enumerations, and then has some column which specifies the enumeration type.
- Store each enumeration definition in an isolated, separate table.

Which is the better way to go, especially with regards to performance? The database in question receives a large number of INSERTs and DELETEs and relatively fewer reads.

Comment: Separate enumeration tables, hands down. Better performance and way simpler to code, to debug, and to test.

Comment: This is a duplicate. I've answered a question just like this a few years back, I just can't find it.

Comment: [one table to rule them all](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approch-good)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  Separate tables have a big advantage.  You can define foreign key relationships that enforce the type of the column for the referencing tables.

A second advantage is that there might be different data columns for different types.  For instance, a countries table might have ISO2 and ISO3 codes and currency.  A cities table might have a timezone.

One occasion where a single table can be handy is for internationalization.  For translating values into separate languages, I find it convenient to have them all in one place.

There is also a space advantage for a single table.  Tables in SQL are stored on pages -- and many reference tables will be smaller than one page.  That leaves a lot of unused space.  Storing them in one table "compacts" them, eliminating that space.  However, that is rarely a real consideration in the modern world.

In general, though, you would use separate tables unless you had a compelling reason to use a single table.